# HTML how to combine rowspan and colspan to make merge 4 colums into 1

Tags: html

I need to merge 4 colums (2 in row 1 and 2 under them) together.

I have tried the following, but it does not work. BTW the code is the whole table I need to create.

I need to get letter G..

Link to the table I need to code: https://prnt.sc/rm1vo0

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td rowspan="2">E</td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"colspan="2">G</td>
    <td>H</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the codes below.

```html
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">A</td>
            <td colspan="2">B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td rowspan="2">E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">G</td>
            <td>H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I</td>
            <td>J</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```